# How to do linear regression prediction for each level of a category variable and apply it on a new data frame

Tags: regression, r

I would like to have an `lm()` prediction per country as a new column for df1 based on the models per each country that should be based on data frame df.

```
    df <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country
                                3        9         7 a
                                3        8         4 b
                                1        2         8 c
                                1        2         3 a
                                1        8         3 a
                                6        1         2 a
                                6        7         1 b
                                6        1         5 c   ",header = TRUE)
df1<-read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country
                         6        4         5 a
                         4        5         3 a
                         3        8         2 a
                         1        6         4 b
                         3        5         1 a
                         2        2         1 b
                         9        9         4 b
                         8        9         5 c
                         2        3         1 c",header = TRUE)
```

So the result should be as below where country "a" prediction should be based on the lm() model for that country only and so on..( fake numbers for the last column - it's only for the data frame's structure)

```
R2<-read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country regress
                         6        4         5     a           5.2
                         4        5         3     a           5.4
                         3        8         2     a           4.8 
                         1        6         4     b           6.6 
                         3        5         1     a           5.0 
                         2        2         1     b           6.1
                         9        9         4     b           6.7
                         8        9         5     c           2.3
                         2        3         1     c           3.1 ",header = TRUE)
```

I tried this code(below) but I would like to see if there is a better code without the looping .How can I improve it ?

```
     for(i in levels(df$Country))
 { 

         fit_pred <- predict(lm(target~birds, data=df), newdata=df1)

        res <- fit_pred
         g<-as.data.frame(cbind(df1,res))
         g

 }
 g
```

Comment: This will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481107/linear-model-within-a-loop-loop-used-to-subset-data/32481445#32481445

Comment: Thanks @ AntoniosK,  I tried one of the examples: lm <- unlist(lapply(split(df,df$Country),function(chunk){
    return(predict(lm(target~birds, data=chunk))[[1]])
}) But I don't understand how to have the prediction on the new data frame (df1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that your *for* loop is doing what you describe, or want it to do. It doesn't index either of the data frames by `Country`.

I think what you want is to

1. Fit a model on `df` where each Country has a different intercept and slope
2. Apply the estimated parameters from the model to `df1`

Here's the code to do this:

```
df$Country <- factor(df$Country)
M <- lm(target ~ birds * Country, data=df)
df1$yhat <- predict(M, df1)
df1$res <- df1$target - df1$yhat
```

Returns

```
> M

Call:
lm(formula = target ~ birds * Country, data = df)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)           birds        Countryb        Countryc  birds:Countryb  birds:Countryc  
          3.95           -0.24           23.05            7.05           -2.76           -4.76
```

and

```
> df1
  target birds wolfs Country   yhat    res
1      6     4     5       a   2.99   3.01
2      4     5     3       a   2.75   1.25
3      3     8     2       a   2.03   0.97
4      1     6     4       b   9.00  -8.00
5      3     5     1       a   2.75   0.25
6      2     2     1       b  21.00 -19.00
7      9     9     4       b   0.00   9.00
8      8     9     5       c -34.00  42.00
9      2     3     1       c  -4.00   6.00
```